# Parallelize For loops in Numpy and Dask for creating a multi-dimensional histogram

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I have three 4-dimensional arrays need to be binned to create a multi-dimensional histogram. In the example below, I have used numpy, but the actual arrays are being read in from a NetCDF file using xarray.

I know that xarray uses dask in the backend, and I have tried creating a small dask cluster on the machine I am using, which has 20 cores, but I don't get any speedup in the for loops, but I do get the speedup in the digitize step.

I am hoping someone can help me parallelize the for loop based on dask.

```
import numpy as np

# Initial datasets
s = np.random.rand(5,2,3,4)
ws = np.random.rand(5,2,3,4)
wd = np.random.rand(5, 2, 3, 4)

# Digitize to different bins
s_map = np.digitize(s, [0, .5, 1])
ws_map = np.digitize(ws, [0, .25, .5, .75, 1])
wd_map = np.digitize(wd, [.25, .5, 1])

# Get indexes that have values
s_ids = np.unique(s_map)
ws_ids = np.unique(ws_map)
wd_ids = np.unique(wd_map)

# Create output array
count = np.zeros((s_ids.size, ws_ids.size, wd_ids.size) + s.shape[1:])

# Loop over each of the maps to count how many values fall into each bin
for i, s_id in enumerate(s_ids):
    s_mask = s_map == s_id

    for j, ws_id in enumerate(ws_ids):
        ws_mask = s_mask & (ws_map == ws_id)

        for k, wd_id in enumerate(wd_ids):
            mask = ws_mask & (wd_map == wd_id)
            count[i, j, k, ...] += np.count_nonzero(mask, axis=0)
```

Comment: H @Neil Davis, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: @user32185 thank you for your comment. I have updated the example in an attempt to better meet the requirements of the links you showed above.

Comment: Hi @Neil Davis could you explain what is your code actually doing?

Comment: @user32185 Sure, the code is being used to create a multi-dimensional histogram in time, at many 3D locations. This is for wind energy analysis, where we have timeseries of wind speed, wind direction, and atmospheric stability. We then create classes of those variables, for example 10 degree wind direction bins. Then for each point (x, y, z) we need to count how many times end up in each combination of the bins.